# Duplicating a Mesh and moving it

Tags: matlab, 3d, vertex

I've got a source mesh, which I want to duplicate (I can do that), but now I want to move that duplicate, i.e change the coordinate of the vertices, in such a way that if it's superimposed onto the source mesh, there will be an offset.

Comment: **GREAT** always helping one antoher _good to see_

Comment: How is the source mesh stored? You just need to offset all coordinates by a small bit and that would be good enough

Comment: I've extracted the vertices and faces into seperate txt files and stored them inside matlab as variable V and F respectively

Comment: Just do what I said in teh second part of my comment

Comment: how do i add the offset to the x,y,z values in V then ? `V + rand´ ?

Comment: `V=V+0.1*ones(size(V));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a small offset (you may need a different value other than 0.1)

```
V=V+0.1*ones(size(V));
```